# Suppress output when running pyInstaller-generated executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've been able to successfully generate a Windows executable from Python 3.4 code by using pyInstaller.

However, each time I run the executable (a console application), it will output the following before my code starts:

```
_bz2
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI65322\_bz2.pyd
_lzma
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI65322\_lzma.pyd
lxml.etree
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI65322\lxml.etree.pyd
_socket
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI65322\_socket.pyd
_ssl
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI65322\_ssl.pyd
_hashlib
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI65322\_hashlib.pyd
select
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI65322\select.pyd
_ctypes
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI65322\_ctypes.pyd
win32api
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI65322\win32api.pyd
unicodedata
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_MEI65322\unicodedata.pyd
```

I assume this is the pyInstaller bootloader process as described [here](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#the-bootstrap-process-in-detail). I was wondering if there is a way to suppress this output, without suppressing the output generated by my own Python code?

Additional info:

- Generated a single executable file (using the `--onefile` option)
- Python 3.4 running on Windows 7 Enterprise
- pyInstaller version 3.0 (dev), taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tree/python3).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1140). The temporary solution is to clone and install `matysek`'s [fork](https://github.com/matysek/pyinstaller/tree/python3). Since `matysek` is a frequent PyInstaller committer, this should be reasonably safe. (Your mileage may vary, of course.)

This has been noted in the aforementioned issue and hence will probably be resolved shortly in PyInstaller's official "python3" branch.